# Reading Delimited Input in Lisp

Tags: input, lisp

In Common Lisp, I need to capture user input in the form of a list of reals. This list is terminated by two zeros in a row. For example, `5.0 0 6.0 3 2.0 5 1.0 7 13.0 8 0 0` should return the list `(5.0 0 6.0 3 2.0 5 1.0 7 13.0 8)`.

I've come across the function `read-delimited-list`, which takes a single character as an ending point. I can stop at a *single* zero, but I'm not sure how to expand this function, and I don't know of another function that takes a delimited string instead of a char.

*EDIT* Thanks to the accepted answer, I've developed the following:

```
(butlast (loop for y = -1 then x for x = (read stream) until (and (= 0 x) (= 0 y))
    collect x)))
```

It seems a bit more readable to me (and at this point I'm openly admiting that my Lisp eyes are only 3 days old), and I'm not sure about performance implications (does `collect` append or reverse the list after the loop exits scope? is there an easier way to chop off the last element, or simply not append it?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such simple case you can just use `read` in a loop, collect the results read so far and stop, when the last two are zeros.

```
(defun read-double-zero-terminated-list (stream)
  (do* ((prev -1 val)
        (val (read stream) (read stream))
        list)
       ((and (zerop prev) (zerop val)) (reverse (cdr list)))
     (push val list)))
```

`read-delimited-list` is intended for the cases of creating specialized syntax, so it's probably overkill here.

Comment: Not overkilling, just plain wrong. `read-delimited-list` works at a **character** level input... I bet efritz doesn't want to stop on a `0.17`.

Comment: Why are you using do*? It seems to me like it would also work with do   loop.

Comment: Remember to always set `*read-eval*` to `nil` when using `read` like this, to protect against `#.`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to parse numbers in Common Lisp is to use the library `parse-number`.  If your user input can be read line by line, you can simply split the lines on whitespace and use `parse-number` on the results.